# How to understand the connectionless packet delivery service that Datagram packets implement?

Tags: java, packet, datagram

When reading the description for Class DatagramPacket in documentation, I noticed this class is described as to implement a connectionless packet delivery service, but I do not understand what it means by "connectionless". If service is connectionless, how could it deliver information from client to server or from server to client? Below is the description for Class DatagramPacket in documentation.
[DatagramPacket documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rXC7.png)

I am familiar with TCP, and know server and client communicate with sockets, and convey data through streams(in & out).But for UDP, could anybody kindly tell me its mechanism on client/server communication and conveying data in plain words? Thx.